# How to find from collection by its reference

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I searched in all places and in the Mongoose's documentation without success.

I wanna search all content in my users collection that is from type 'Admin'.

```
UserTypeSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    user_type: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        }
    ],
}, {
    strict: true
});

UserSchema = new Schema({
    user_type: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'UserType'
    },
}, {
    strict: true
});
```

Query to find users by type (being another model as reference)

```
User
    .find()
    .populate('user_type', 'name', null, {'user_type': 'Admin'})
    .exec(function(err, users) {
        res.send(users);
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possiblities, either you query the type schema for admin and use the returned object to query for users like this:

```
Type.findOne({name: 'Admin'}, function(err, type) {
    User.find({user_type: type._id}, function(err, users) {
        ...
    })
})
```

Or if you have a reference in your type schema to users, couldn't you simply do:

```
Type.findOne({name: 'Admin'}, function(err, type) {
    var users = type.user_type;
    ...
})
```

Or am I reading your schema wrong?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your second possibility returns an empty array. Do you have any tips?

Comment: That is probably because user_type is empty, the user_type array won't be populated automatically because you have a link the other way around. You need to put the users there manually for it to work.

Comment: Yes, thanks! I choose the first option :) Worked like a charm.